# Present perfect (has/has been)

Tags: tense, perfect-constructions

Just when I think I have understood Perfect tenses, something comes up and I just can't get my head around it.

In my book it says that:

`We can also use the present perfect for states.`

*`1. The shop has been open a week.`*

Why not *`Opened`*? Is *`Opened`* wrong here?

I read that `has been` is present perfect in passive form. Is above sentence in passive form?

Please consider this example from a different source:

*`2. John has been chosen to play football for Team A against Team B.`* (is this passive form too? If yes, what is its active form?)

We also use `have been + ING` in Present Perfect Progressive. (is this `have been` also passive same as Present Perfect Passive `have been`?)

Comment: **have been + ING** is nothing to do with "passive" constructions. Passive constructions involve a ***past participle*** for which the associated "subject" of the verb is unspecified, such as *They have been **eaten*** (unspecified people ate whatever "they" refers to) - as opposed to *They have been **eating***, which describes what they've been doing using an "active" continuous verb form.

Answer (score 0):

In your N.1 there is a form of the Active Voice. "Open" is a Subject Complement.

N.2 is a Passive Voice construction where the Past Participle of the verb "to choose" is a part of a compound verbal predicate. Its active form will be: "They have chosen John to play football...".

"Have been + ING" is, to put it simpler, a perfect of the Present Continuous, i.e. "John is playing football" - "John has been *(have + Past Participle of "to be")* playing football".

Comment: so 'open' is a state here : Adj.? What about 'opened'?

Comment: "Opened" plays the same role in the sentence as "chosen" does. "Notwithstanding this shop has been opened by sha3.nic this year it quickly became successful".

Comment: @Eugene: Your example is wrong. "Although this shop was opened by sha3.nic this year, it has been (or it quickly became) successful".

Comment: "Open" is an adjective in your sentence 1. Examples of "has been opened": The shop has been opened each morning this week by its owner." "After lengthy arguments, the shop has been opened by the Mayor of London."

Comment: @Old Brixtonian "Open" is an adjective as a part of speech but it is a SC as far as its role in the sentence is concerned.

Comment: @Old Brixtonian Sorry, but what's wrong with "Notwithstanding the fact that the shop has been opened by the Mayor of London [by Mr. Sha3.nic] this year, it quickly became successful"??